# how to find and extract text from webpage in c#

Tags: c#, html

i want to know how can i get data from webpage

example :

```
<li id="hello1">about me
    <ul class="square">
        <li><strong>name: john</strong></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

i want to read john in front of name:  so how i cant read it in c#
oh i have tried to use [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)  :( but due to its poor documentation i was not able to use so need help .

Comment: can you please tell us, what you have tried?

Comment: i mean i have downloaded HTML agility Pack , but i have not find any examples in documentation file, so that i learn its use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load(yourStream);
var nameElement= doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//li[@id='hello1']").InnerText;
//name would contain `about me name: john`
Regex.Match(nameElement,@"(?<=name:\s*)\w+").Value;//john
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used HTML Agility Pack before and it is great tool

```
HtmlDocument document = new HtmlDocument(); 

document.LoadHtml(YourHTML);
var collection = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//li[@id='hello1']");
```